# Custom cell with multiple images and a label inconsistently displays

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` class for displaying multiple images which I connected and built the elements for with interface builder xib.  I made sure that the imageView sizes in size inspector match the dimensions of the png's I would like to display.  This is my header file for custom cell

```
@interface MultipleImageCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *type;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *sold;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatar;

@end
```

I have not changed anything in cell implementation file and it is as auto-generated.  In my table view controller class, for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I registered Nib and set up the new cell type and set correct identifier with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.  Then I attempt to modify the properties of my custom cell with a few switch statements.  this causes the cells in the simulator to be loaded inconsistently.  they look ok if I shut down the simulator, start it again, but once I start manipulating them, some images show up, some don't, or the wrong image shows.

This is code inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
//set the type for every cell
[cell.type setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:type]];

    if (sold) {
        //put in sold icon
        [cell.sold setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sold"]];


        if (self.user isEqualToString:originalSender]) {

            cell.name.text = sender;
            return cell;


        } else {
            //anonymous posting

            cell.name.text = nil;
            [cell.avatar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"man"]];
            return cell;
        }
    }
    //default cell
    cell.name.text = nil;
    cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Which function doesn't show correct image ?

Comment: the image type is always consistently displayed, but sold, avatar image, and text display inconsistently and often times the wrong image, it seems as if it's skipping and ignoring switch statements somehow

Comment: You need to implement the if else properly.. In your case you have assigned images for only true conditions, what about false conditions? For eg. you implemented `if(sold)` not `else` and `if (self.user isEqualToString:originalSender])` is not implemented while `else` is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that when the system recycles your cells the old cells still have their images.

Try clearing your image views when preparing a cell for reuse. Implement the following in your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
 - (void)prepareForReuse;
{
    self.avatar.image = nil;
    self.type.image = nil;
    self.sold.image = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the cell before setting all properties of the CustomeCell.

```
[cell.type setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:type]];

//default cell
cell.name.text = nil;
cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man"];

if (sold) {
    //put in sold icon
    [cell.sold setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sold"]];


    if (self.user isEqualToString:originalSender]) {
        cell.name.text = sender;
        cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:senderImage]; 
        //I assume you have image for sender. 
    }
}

return cell;
```

Comment: That's right. Return should be in the end of everything.